# Python import Julia leads to freeze in other part of the script

Tags: python, parallel-processing, julia

I call a Julia script with this command in Python:

```
import julia
j = julia.Julia(compiled_modules=False)
j.include("tests/test.jl")
result = j.test()
```

After that I exit the python file in which Julia is executed, do a bunch of calculations with the result and start a python parallel processing pool. The process freezes without an error occurring at the point where it should return the result out of the Pool.

With Julia I replicated a process that I have been using in Python for speed performance. The results are exactly the same. My calculations therefor cannot be the cause of the error. Can you please point out what other things could have caused the error and how I can circumvent them?

Comment: Your code does not appear to include the portions that your question addresses. Please [edit] it to include a minimal, reproducible example. What do you mean by "exit the python file in which Julia is executed" - Does your application consists of separate scripts? Do you do "a bunch of calculations" in Julia, Python, or the multiprocess Pool? How do you "start a python parallel processing pool"?

Answer (score 1):

When doing multiprocessing in Julia you might run into a compiler chase when several Julia processes try to compile the same piece of code (including the same set of packages).

Hence you need to make sure that all your Julia stuff is pre-compiled before going into multiprocessing. The best way is to put all of your Julia code into a [package](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1.4/creating-packages/index.html). 
You than need to run o a single worker:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.activate(".")  #this assumes that you are in the folder of your package
using YourModuleName
```

When this finished running on a single worker you can run whatever you need across all parallel processes.

Basically when you have many Julia parallel jobs using Python does not look like a good idea to control the concurrency at all. 
I would rather write a distributed Julia code and call it from Python. In order to avoid freezing your Julia code will look more or less like this:

```
using Distributed, Pkg
addprocs(4) # insert whatever you need
@everywhere using Distributed, Pkg
Pkg.activate(".")
@everywhere Pkg.activate(".")
using YourModuleName
@everywhere using YourModuleName
res = @distributed (+) for i in 1:10_000
      YourModuleName.dosomething(i)
end
```

This assumes that the results of `dosomething(i)` can be aggragated using `+` function (usually I rather `append` some `DataFrame`s here)